# Jquery. Order a list of names alphabetically

Tags: jquery

I got a list of names (firstname and lastname) on a page. I want the user to be able to sort this list on either firstname or lastname using jQuery (or normal javascript). How can this be done?

```
<ul>
<li>Michael Scott</li>
<li>Jonathan Torry</li>
</ul>
```

Very thankful for all input!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Array.sort() is what you need

```
var items = [];
$('ul li').each(function(){
   items.push($(this).html());
})
items.sort();
```

Example here : http://jsfiddle.net/jomanlk/7UzNZ/

Comment: Looking interesting. How can I change order of the names? Ascending and descending?

Comment: You could simply call `items.reverse();` on the array to reverse it

Comment: items.reverse(); instead of items.sort(); did not change the order.

Comment: No, I meant you have to call `items.reverse()` after you call `items.sort()`. Sort will sort it initially, and reverse will simply give you the reversed order. Did that help?

Answer (score -1):

Try my plugin http://www.athos99.com/listorder/type.html

For ordering fistname and lastname, change your list like this :

```
<ul id="ul1">
<li><span>Michael</span> <span>Scott</span></li>
<li><span>Jonathan</span> <span>Torry</span></li>
</ul>
```

For ordering by firstname

```
 $('#ul1').listorder( { child:'li', childValue:function(){return $(this.children([0]).text();} });
```

For ordering by lastname

```
 $('#ul1').listorder( { child:'li', childValue:function(){return $(this.children([1]).text();} });


$(this.children([0])   select the 1st span
$(this.children([1])   select the 2nd span
```